# Efficient way to construct list of sub-subdirectories in python

Tags: python, file-system

I have a directory that includes a number of subdirectories. Each subdirectories contains subdirectories of its own. I'd like to construct a list of all sub-subdirectories in python. Here is my attempt:

```
import os 

list_of_lists = [[sub_dir + '/' + sub_subdir for sub_subdir in os.listdir(my_dir + '/' + sub_dir)] for sub_dir in os.listdir(my_dir)]

flat_list = [item for sublist in list_of_lists for item in sublist]
```

Is there a better/more efficient/more aesthetic way to construct this?

To clarify, here is an example:

```
My_dir
|
|--sub_dir_1
|     |
|     |--sub_sub_dir_1
|     |
|     |--sub_sub_dir_2
|
|--sub_dir_2
|     |
|     |--sub_sub_dir_1
|
|--sub_dir_3
      |
      |--sub_sub_dir_1
      |
      |--sub_sub_dir_2
      |
      |--sub_sub_dir_2
```

In this example, the output that I'm looking for is `['sub_dir_1/sub_sub_dir_1', 'sub_dir_1/sub_sub_dir_2', 'sub_dir_2/sub_sub_dir_1', 'sub_dir_3/sub_sub_dir_1', 'sub_dir_3/sub_sub_dir_2', 'sub_dir_3/sub_sub_dir_3']`.

Comment: Your example has only two levels. Do you care about deeper hierarchy?

Comment: [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) is what you are looking for. e.g. `[folder for folder, folders, files in os.walk(".") if not folders]`

Comment: @vnp No, I don't.

Comment: @stefan Beautiful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The os module provides many functions to interact with operating system features, and one such method is `os.walk()`, which generates and fetch the files and folders in a directory tree. It can traverse the tree either top-down or bottom-up search, and by default, it sets as top-down search.

**What you are looking for is to get the subdirectories with absolute path** and using the `os.walk()` method you can retrieve the subdirectories in the absolute path.

Below code gets both files and sub-directories but you can modify it to get only the subfolders according to your need.

```
# import OS module
import os

# List all the files and directories
path = "C:\Projects\Tryouts"
for (root, directories, files) in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
    for name in directories:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

The other alternate way is to use the `glob` module. The glob module helps you retrieve the files/path matching a specified pattern as the glob supports the wildcard search. We can get both files and folders using the glob module.

Source: [List Files and folders in a Directory](https://itsmycode.com/python-list-files-in-a-directory/)

Comment: You've been dropping links to your blog in your answers. Please take a look at ["how not to be a spammer"](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) and consider making the affiliation more explicitly apparent in your answers.